# How to pass a parameter value from view to controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to pass a parameter value from view to my controller but it is not working. Here is the method which I am using:

```
@Html.ActionLink("English","ResourseLang","mvcResourseController", new { lang = "value" })
```

In the controller the `lang` value is `null`

```
public ActionResult ResourseLang(String lang) {
    String ab = lang;
    return view("Index");
}
```

Comment: Can you make you code more readable and also give more details about the `Controller`. Check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I don't think that's how MVC is supposed to work... from what I know, your model is supposed to mirror the data from the view, and any selection in lists or dropdowns immediately causes an update of the "currently selected object in this list" in the model's data, so that button presses don't need any additional data from the view to execute their operations; it's all in the model. Or, at least, the controller should be able to request such data from the view at the moment of the button press.

Comment: @Malik Umar Sultan, Please accept answer if answer helped you. So by that you will give credit to user who have posted answer for you. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You will get like below:

```
@Html.ActionLink("English","ResourseLang", new { @lang = "value" })
```

At controller side code will be same as you wrote.

```
public ActionResult ResourseLang(String lang) {
    String ab = lang;
    return view("Index");
}
```

**Ref :**

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/ajax-actionlink-and-html-actionlink-in-mvc/

You can test `MVC` code online here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/CsMvc

Answer (score 1):

You are using a wrong `Html.ActionLink` overload and missing html attributes. Pass `null` if you are not adding any html attributes. So you should use it like below:

**Razor:**

```
@Html.ActionLink(
      "English",                //Action Link Text
      "ResourseLang",           //Action Name
      "mvcResourseController",  //Controller Name
      new { lang = "value" },   //Route Values
      null                      //Html Attributes
)
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult ResourseLang(string lang) {
    string ab = lang;
    return view("Index");
}
```